# Can I group CI steps together so that failing one of them will prevent next steps from running but not fail the job?

Tags: circleci

We use CircleCI configuration version 2.1. I have a command consisting of several steps, but it's just to send some Slack notifications; it shouldn't fail the build if the command itself fails. I can put

```
set +e
<actual commands>
true
```

in each `run` step, but ideally I want the following steps *of this command* not to run, but any steps which happen after the command should run as normal.

If I could guarantee the command was the last one on in any job which uses it, I could also do

```
{
  <actual commands>
} || circleci-agent step halt
```

but this is just begging for someone to forget the rule (unless there is a way to enforce it?).

My final workaround is

```
if [ -n "$COMMAND_FAILING" ]; exit 0; fi
{
  <actual commands>
} || echo "export COMMAND_FAILING=true" >> $BASH_ENV
```

But this still has 2 problems:

1. It applies only to `run` steps. In my particular case the only other step is [`slack/notify`](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/slack#commands-notify) which already ignores *most* errors, but not all.
2. It's something I have to do at each step instead of the command level.

Is there a better way?